# Кодировка ms sql

Tags: sql, база-данных, sql-server, unicode

Пишу запрос Insert в базу данных ms sql и указываю поля на русском языке, но сохраняет их как знаки вопроса (??????). Как можно это починить, тип данных - nchar

Comment: подумать, точно ли нужен nchar а не nvarchar и испрвить инссерт на `... values (N'Василий')`

Comment: [Prefix a Unicode character string constants with the letter N to signal UCS-2 or UTF-16 input, depending on whether an SC collation is used or not. Without the N prefix, the string is converted to the default code page of the database that may not recognize certain characters. Starting with SQL Server 2019 (15.x), when a UTF-8 enabled collation is used, the default code page is capable of storing UNICODE UTF-8 character set.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/nchar-and-nvarchar-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#:~:text=Prefix%20a%20Unicode,8%20character%20set.)

Answer (score 2):

Исправление вставки на `... values (N'Василий')` помогло.